# Functor definition in category theory

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, tikz-cd

Is there a nice way to defined functors in latex? There is always the following pattern:

```
Domain ----> Codomain
  a    |----> Fa
 f|            | Ff
 \|/   |----> \|/
  b           Fb
```

Is there a more "semantic" approach than TikZ for this which allow to factor out the parts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you asking for something like this?  I know there is the `tikz-cd` package explicitly for commutative diagrams, but you mentioned you would like to avoid the `tikz` apparatus.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\newcommand\functor[1][l]{\csname#1functor\endcsname}
\newcommand\lfunctor[3]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$#2$}%
  \kern\wd0%
  \ensurestackMath{\Centerstack[c]{#1\\ \mathllap{#2\;\,}\mathclap{\DownArrow}\\#3}}%
}
\newcommand\rfunctor[3]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$#2$}%
  \ensurestackMath{\Centerstack[c]{#1\\\mathclap{\DownArrow}\mathrlap{\,\;#2}\\#3}}%
  \kern\wd0%
}
\newcommand\functormapsto{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{\Centerstack[c]{\longmapsto\\ \\\longmapsto}}}}
\setstackgap{L}{1.3\normalbaselineskip}
\newcommand\DownArrow{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\longrightarrow$\,}}
\begin{document}
\[
\functor[l]{a}{f}{b}
\functormapsto
\functor[r]{F_a}{F_f}{F_b}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: exactly. this looks like a great technique which can generalize. thank you

Comment: I love the subtle use of reflection and all this untyped nonsense while writing category theory. it really makes you think at value proposition...

Comment: @nicolas I am glad the solution meets your need.

Answer (score 5):

I'd go with `tikz-cd` and a key value interface:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz-cd}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\functor}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { nicolas/functor } { #2 }
  \nicolas_functor:n { #1 }
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { nicolas/functor }
 {
  domain   .tl_set:N = \l_nicolas_functor_domain_tl,
  codomain .tl_set:N = \l_nicolas_functor_codomain_tl,
  name     .tl_set:N = \l_nicolas_functor_name_tl,
  source   .tl_set:N = \l_nicolas_functor_source_tl,
  target   .tl_set:N = \l_nicolas_functor_target_tl,
  map      .tl_set:N = \l_nicolas_functor_map_tl,

  name   .initial:n = F,
  source .initial:n = a,
  target .initial:n = b,
  map    .initial:n = f,
 }

\dim_new:N \g_nicolas_functor_space_dim

\cs_new:Nn \nicolas_functor:n
 {
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand~replacement=\&,#1]
  \dim_gset:Nn \g_nicolas_functor_space_dim { \pgfmatrixrowsep }
  \l_nicolas_functor_domain_tl
  \arrow[r,"\l_nicolas_functor_name_tl"] \&
  \l_nicolas_functor_codomain_tl
  \\[\dim_eval:n {1ex-\g_nicolas_functor_space_dim}]
  \l_nicolas_functor_source_tl
  \arrow[r,mapsto] \arrow[d,swap,"\l_nicolas_functor_map_tl"] \&
  \l_nicolas_functor_name_tl \l_nicolas_functor_source_tl
  \arrow[d,"\l_nicolas_functor_name_tl \l_nicolas_functor_map_tl"]
  \\
  \l_nicolas_functor_target_tl
  \arrow[r,mapsto] \&
  \l_nicolas_functor_name_tl \l_nicolas_functor_target_tl
  \end{tikzcd}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\functor{
  domain=X,
  codomain=Y,
}

\bigskip

\functor{
  domain=\mathbf{Ring},
  codomain=\mathbf{Set},
  name=U,
  source=R,
  target=S,
}

\bigskip

\functor[row sep=huge]{
  domain=\mathbf{Ring},
  codomain=\mathbf{Set},
  name=U,
  source=R,
  map=\varphi,
  target=S,
}

\end{document}
```

In the optional argument you can pass `tikz-cd` options; the key names should be clear from the examples.

[image]

Comment: I know this is kinda old, but could you please post a more user-friendly code?

Comment: @big-lion The idea is that the user interface is easy. The code is not as scary as it may seem: a key-value interface is set up, which is used for building the diagrams.

Comment: Very useful indeed, anyhow, can I customize the command to get for instance UR,US=something U\phi=something_other. So one can use the duiagram to specify the action of the functor.

Comment: For instance here: \functor{
  domain=\operatorname{LieGrp},
  codomain=\operatorname{LieAlg},
  name=\operatorname{Lie},
  source=G,
  target=H,
} I would like to specify $Lie(G)=\mathfrak{g}$ $Lie(f)=df$ and so on

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta I'm not sure what you mean. Perhaps a new question with more details is better.